# How to get multiple user and password logins on a HITRON router

Tags: wireless-networking, user-accounts, login-screen

I have people who go to my house and I want them to have an individual login for themselves **( I know its not needed but I still want it)**

For example:

**(try to click the network to log in and it looks like this before you log in)**

Username:

Password:

And each person has there own login like so:

**(user 1)**

Username: firstlas000

Password: HMGH18

**(User 2)**

Username: dixonhen000 **(I'm using a template for the users this is what it is gonna look like)**

Password: Pass200

Comment: You probably shouldn't be posting _actual_ eventual usernames and passwords on a public website like that...

Comment: Please clarify if you're asking about Router Control Panel Logins, or Wireless Networking logins.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with WPA2-Enterprise (this can also be called things like "WPA2 with EAP" or "WPA2 with 802.1X"). Look to see if your Hitron model has that kind of feature. You didn't specify which model you have, and feature sets can vary widely from model to model within a single vendor's product lines, so I can't look this up for you.

If your router has this feature, it will usually also have a place for you to point it at a RADIUS authentication server on your network. You would need to set up that RADIUS server yourself, possibly by installing an open source RADIUS server package such as FreeRADIUS on some always-on machine on your network. You set up the login credentials (the username/password pairs) on the RADIUS server.

Some routers may have a built-in authentication server allowing you to set up login credentials for your users right on your router without requiring a separate RADIUS server, but this is less common.

If WPA2-Enterprise isn't an option on your router, then it probably isn't a very sophisticated router and probably won't support the other common way of doing username/password login credentials, which is known as "Captive Portal".